# Zend Framework action stack functionality in Symfony 2

Tags: zend-framework, symfony, stack, action

Hi I would like to be able to dispatch a set of actions within my controller and to inject their responses in specific places of the layout. It was really easy to achieve with Zend Framework and its [ActionStack controller  helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.actionstack).

Is there any functionality like this in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). It is close enough to your requirement.